# Hudson, setting a customized view as default

Tags: hudson, hudson-plugins

I made a very nice customized view for my various hudson jobs. I was wondering if it is possible to set a default hudson view so I when go to hudson it gives me my very nice customized view with build history, and pie and bar graphs. Just makes it easier since I open and work with it everyday.

It could cut crucial seconds off my development time :P

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under "Manage Hudson" > Configure System

There is an option to choose the default view.

Answer (score 3):

You can set your default view under your user preferences: click on your username, then *Configure*.

Or you can set the default view for all users under *Manage Hudson* -> *Configure System*.